# Exact Location to keep JSP files in a spring Boot App

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am new to spring boot and I have created a simple app using spring boot but I am not sure where I should keep my views(JSP's and HTML). I tried keeping it in src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/ folder but somehow its not rendering my views neither I am getting any error message. I have tried both jar and war packaging types. I have also put

> spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
>
> spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp

in application.properties file.

[image]

My pom.xml file is as follows:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.spring.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>rest-api-database-new</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>rest-api-database-new</name>
<description>Rest Api connecting to database</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.12.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
        <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
  <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
  <version>4.6.1</version>
</dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: anything under WEB-INF is not visible to the client

Comment: where should I keep my views then. I mean at which location ?

Comment: How about directly below webapp?

Comment: Keep it outside `WEB_INF` under `webapp.`

Comment: I tried keeping it outside but this time it gave me the jsp file to download and does not rendered on browser...

Comment: LAT : https://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-boot/spring-boot-jsp-view-example/